# How to redirectcProfile Stats.print_stats() output into logging?

Tags: python, logging

Stats.print_stats() print the output to std_output by default, or you can give a stream to the Stats. How can I apply logging into this stream?

I have a logging handler to a file :

> ```
> log = logging.getLogger('log1')
> debughandler = logging.FileHandler("debug." + LogFilename, 'w', 'utf-8')
> debughandler.setFormatter(formatter)
> debughandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
> log.addHandler(debughandler)
> ```

now I just want to redirect the output of Stats into this log handler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a io.StringIO() as a stream to hold the result:

```
s = io.StringIO()
pstat = pstats.Stats('restatslex', stream=s)
pstat.sort_stats('time').print_stats(20)
log.info(s.getvalue())
```

then the stats information is in the log.